# How and where are Windows passwords stored on the disk, and what algorithms are used to hash them?

Tags: c#, windows, hash, passwords

I would like to implement a version the hash algorithm in a C# application, and need to know how Windows hashes and checks the passwords. I also need to know where they are stored. As far as I know, in the SAM file under C:\Windows\System32\config. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing tricky here.  the NTLM hash is just the MD4 of the unicode password.  MD4 is irresponsibly weak, so you will need a comprehensive crypto lib, like [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). MS has no native methods for it.

also, the [best reference on the topic](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html).

using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;

I think those cover it.  I hope...

here is one that returns it as a byte[], which you can convert as needed.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert Password to NT Hash.  Convert to unicode and MD4
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="passwordIn">password In</param>
    /// <returns>NT Hash as byte[]</returns>
    public static byte[] NTHashAsBytes(string passwordIn)
    {
        MD4Digest md = new MD4Digest();
        byte[] unicodePassword = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordIn));


        md.BlockUpdate(unicodePassword, 0, unicodePassword.Length);
        byte[] hash = new byte[16];
        md.DoFinal(hash, 0);


        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: I had no idea... It sounds like a custom hash algorithm to be honest.

Comment: Custom implementation of some standard crypto stuff. The handshakes also use algorithms that were current when created.  ntlmv1 uses DES and v2 uses HMAC-MD5

Comment: Okay, but as far as the stored hashes are concerned, it's just MD4 of the password in Unicode format?

Comment: if you are talking about stored in windows, heck no!  They are triple encrypted and obfuscated etc. etc.  However, there are tons of tools to "dump" the hashes, if you have local admin access.  The tools decrypt and get you the hash all in one.

Comment: Well this is mostly about analyzing hashes as they are stored on the disk. Maybe it wasn't worded correctly, but what I'm really asking is how the hashes are stored on the disk. I'm going to edit my question right now.

Comment: this is one of the better references http://moyix.blogspot.com/2008/02/syskey-and-sam.html there are a few layers of key wrapping and there is no way to do it via c#, unless you pInvoke.  If you are a good pInvoker, then you wouldn't use c#...  :-P   well, that is my case anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Which "Windows" format do you mean?

[NTLMv1 or NTLMv2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)?

[LM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM_hash)?

[DCC/MSCash/MS-Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.msdcc.html)?

[DCC2/MSCash2/MS-Cache2](http://openwall.info/wiki/john/MSCash2)?

See also the question [Windows 7 Password Hash Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17672/39623).

Comment: Whichever is the latest on Windows. I'm assuming this is NTLM v2, correct?

Comment: Also, I think this should be a comment rather than an answer.